# Multi touch : Get Action depending on PointerId

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouch

My app handle one & two fingers touch.
It's possible that the first finger is sending `ACTION_MOVE` action and the second `ACTION_POINTER_UP` in the same time.

So, how can get action for the first finger, and action for the second ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have pointer indexes that you can use in your `MotionEvent.case`. You have different cases according to which finger is down.

> Also keep in mind no matter what the pointer index is, they are both
>   tied to the `MOVE` case. UNLESS you have access to your pointer IDs in which case you can differentiate by ID.

For example, `ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN` will be associated to your second finger.

### Here is a super simple example:

```
switch(action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):

        break;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN): // Second finger

        break;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        if(pointer > 0) {
            x = motionEvent.getX(pointer);
            y = motionEvent.getY(pointer);
        }
        else {
            x = motionEvent.getX();
            y = motionEvent.getY();
        }

        break;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        System.out.println("UP");
        break;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_UP): // Second finger
        System.out.println("1 UP");
        break;
    }
```